# Convert List to Set, then get List having same order

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a List with some duplicate values,

```
myList = [2,7,6,6,9,2,4,2]
```

I want to get unique elements

```
myList  = set(myList)
myListisBack = list(myList)
```

But the problem is that I get

```
[9, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

How can I get the List of that same order as it was like

```
[2,7,6,9,4]
```

Comment: Cheat and use an OrderedDict... `myListisBack = list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(myList))` - this has been asked many times before - just trying to find a comprehensive answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set` is an unordered collection. Use [`collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the order:

```
>>> myList = [2,7,6,6,9,2,4,2]
>>> import collections
>>> list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(myList))
[2, 7, 6, 9, 4]
```